# Why does ArcGIS Pro use only 5% of my CPU even though I activated parallel processing?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, parallel-processing

Whenever I'm trying to project a big raster it takes ages for ArcGIS Pro to finish the task. Therefore I did some research and found out that there is a *Parallel Processing Factor* which I can set. In my understanding the process should be finished the fastest if I set this value to 100%.

However in my case it seems like this does not change anything at all. I'm working on a server with enough power but my CPU usage never goes above 5-6%. How can I speed this up?

[image]

Comment: Hi Ulrichz94! Usually when this happens, it means that the problem is somewhere else - the CPU is idling while it is waiting for data from RAM or disk.  It seems like you have enough RAM, are you storing the datasets locally or on a networked disk?

Comment: @MortenSickel Good point! With this dataset I was indeed working on a networked disk. I tried it now with locally stored data but this increased the CPU usage only to ~ 9%. There is still a lot of unused CPU and RAM capacity left.

Comment: If your job is to process only one raster, this amount of work is probably right. If you are processing a large number of polygons or rasters, parallel processing can speed up the processing, but I don't know if there is a multi-core advantage when processing one large raster. Make sure your work supports this. "https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/analytics/analytics/parallel-geoprocessing-in-arcgis-pro/"

Comment: When you did research and found about `Parallel Processing Factor`, did you confirm the tool you're using actually honors this setting? Not all tools do.

Comment: While some operations are CPU and GPU intensive, GIS is generally *I/O bound*, which means that data should be on a local SSD drive. Some operations don't adapt well to parallel processing, so even if a process is multithreaded, it doesn't mean that you will get 100% CPU utilization.

Comment: I'll also point out from your screen shot, you have 2 other processes running at 37% and 21% CPU -- more than half your CPU is dedicated to "other" work.  If you're doing a bunch of other heavy operations on your PC, those are going to fight with Pro for CPU resources. Setting PP to 100% isn't going to solve the lack of resources. Have you done your test without all the background stuff going on?

Comment: Following all your helpful replies I tried a few things and got interesting results. But first let me answer your questions:

@Urban87 This is a good point and I alread read the article you sent but there is no possibility to project multiple rasters at the same time. So I'm wondering why ArcGIS gives me the possibility to set this factor in the first place when i makes so difference for this tool.

Comment: @Vince I never really expected the tool to use 100% of my CPU but maybe a bit more than just 5%.

Comment: @KHibma Yes, this tool honors Parallel Processing. The other processes were from different users on the server. But even when the CPU usage is around 20% for all users together my ArcGIS Pro Project will not user more than maybe 7% with this tool.

Comment: What I found out:
When I tried a Pairwise Dissolve (which does basically the same as a regular Dissolve but with parallel processing) on 900k Polygons, my CPU usage was about 15-20% which is already much better than the 5% that Project Raster used. It's still strange that changing the Parallel Processing Factor from 100% to 50% did not change anything. So I'm not really sure whats going on in the background here.

Comment: You're working on a server with other people actively on it? You have so many variables in your scenario which makes it really hard to nail down.

Comment: @KHibma Yes, most of the time there are multiple users on our company server (something like 3 - 8 users). I know that this makes the whole thing more complicated but I had similar values when nobody else was on the server so I think my question is still legit. I know that my user profile is allowed to use the whole CPU when necessary (for example with Agisoft Metashape I'm, using 95% of the CPU).